# ForegroundService is not working even with AlarmManager

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to count step 24/7 from my app even app is killed or on background.

So I create service, and register `sensorManager` and `notification` in `onStartCommand()`.

(actually in `onStart()`, `onCreate()`, `onStartCommand()`, all I code)

My notification function code is below:

```
  fun StepCountNotification(context: Context, stepCount: Int?) {
    
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val CHANNEL_ID = "my_app"
                val channel = NotificationChannel(
                    CHANNEL_ID,
                    "MyApp", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
                )
                (context.getSystemService(Service.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager).createNotificationChannel(
                    channel
                )
                val decimal = DecimalFormat("#,###")
                val step = decimal.format(stepCount)
    
                val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_new_alarm_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("$step 걸음")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setShowWhen(false)
                    .build()
                startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
            }
        }
```

If works well but after 1-2 days, step count is killed in some device.

I guess, device itself kills background work for battery usage.

So I register `alarmManager` with INTERVAL_FIFTEEN in onStartCommand() of Service.

Total code of my Service onStartCommand() is below .

```
 override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        // 알람 매니저
        alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val repeatInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES
        val triggerTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatInterval
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, AlarmBroadcastReceiver::class.java)
        pendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            triggerTime,
            repeatInterval,
            pendingIntent
        )


        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        // 기본
        sensorManager =
            applicationContext?.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        step_sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER)
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, step_sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST)

        // 오늘 걸음수 초기화
        userDB.document("$userId").get().addOnSuccessListener { document ->
            var todayStepCountFromDB = document.getLong("todayStepCount") ?: 0
            todayTotalStepCount = todayStepCountFromDB.toInt()

            StepCountNotification(this, todayTotalStepCount)
        }

        // 1. 1분마다 체크 (날짜 바뀔 때)
        dateChangeBroadcastReceiver = DateChangeBroadcastReceiver()
        val dateChangeIntent = IntentFilter()
        dateChangeIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(dateChangeBroadcastReceiver, dateChangeIntent)

        // 2. 날짜 바뀔 때
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).registerReceiver(
            stepInitializeReceiver,
            IntentFilter("NEW_DATE_STEP_ZERO")
        )

        // 3. 핸드폰 꺼질 때
        deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver = DeviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver()
        val deviceShutdownIntent = IntentFilter()
        deviceShutdownIntent.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN)
        applicationContext?.registerReceiver(deviceShutdownBroadcastReceiver, deviceShutdownIntent)

        // 알람 주기적 브로드캐스터
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).registerReceiver(
            BroadcastReregister,
            IntentFilter("ALARM_BROADCAST_RECEIVER")
        );

        return START_STICKY
    }
```

And in alarmManager Broadcastreceiver, I check notifications of user device and if Service's notification is not there, make call Service again.

So I design, if device kills background work by itself, in 15 minutes period, it check notification, and if notification is not there, code assumes that Service is killed and call Service once again.

```
class AlarmBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

        // 브로드캐스트 주기적 등록
        val alarmIntent = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
        alarmIntent.setAction("ALARM_BROADCAST_RECEIVER")
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context!!).sendBroadcast(alarmIntent);

        // 노티피케이션 서비스 호출
        val mNotificationManager =
            context!!.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val statusNotifications = mNotificationManager.activeNotifications
        for (statusNotification in statusNotifications) {
            if (statusNotification.id != NOTIFICATION_ID) {
                val startService = Intent(context, MyService::class.java)
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, startService);
                } else {
                    context.startService(startService);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I check this alarm broadcast receiver works well with log.

And I test this with 4 devices.

3 of them works fine till 2days passed, but 1 device is stopped to track step.

Can you check and guess any suggestion here?

I know that it's hard to make keep working 24/7 on android phone, but I already 2 apps keep tracking steps, which means there's the exact way.

Please help me, any suggestion will be helpful.